# DDEAUTO: Invoke powershell with an encoded command

Tags: windows, powershell, dde

I have a base64 encoding of a command (6475 characters) and I can successfully execute it from the `cmd.exe` command prompt with `powershell -e base64_string`, but when I create the following field in Word:

```
{ DDEAUTO c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe "/k powershell -e base64_string" }
```

I get an error from `powershell` that the command is not properly encoded. I re-checked 100 times, copy pasting the same thing in both the `cmd` command prompt and in Word, I made sure to paste it as plain unformated text, still the error. With single instead of double quotes I get no error, but the command is not being executed: just a blank `cmd` window. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: While the limits don't seem to be documented anywhere, it seems probable that Word does not support a command line of over 6 KB through `DDEAUTO`. The intended use of `DDEAUTO` is to pass a filename to an external command -- those never hit 6 KB, obviously. Try a (much) smaller script first; if that works you know it's a size limit (and you can use doubling to find the actual limit, if you're so inclined).

Comment: @Jeroen I tried it with a very short command now, same error: not properly encoded.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Word 2013. The field code`DDEAUTO "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" "/k powershell -e ZQBjAGgAbwAgAGgAZQBsAGwAbwA="` causes PowerShell to be opened and print `hello` (as the encoded command is `echo hello`) -- after ignoring some warnings from Word concerning this highly dubious technique, of course. Your version of Office/Word may be relevant... as well as what you're trying to achieve, if you're not building an exploit.

Comment: @Jeroen, very strange: when I encode "echo hello" in base64 I get ZWNobyBoZWxsbw== . How did you encode it? When I decode what you have given I get the string echo hello, but with null bytes between each character. This one does execute properly in powershell, is this the format it expect? Still doesn't solve my problem with the long payload though: I checked the hex  dump and it does have null bytes between every character, just like your encoding. Maybe it is the length after all.

Comment: I encoded it per the documentation you get right down at the bottom when you invoke `PowerShell /?`. The string must be Unicode. (The failure of the long payload may still simply be due to the a size limitation in Word.)